# Store angular Html Code of components in database and show like Component

Tags: angular, typescript

i have project that user can edit and add Angular Component code Html  && TS

when i use html code on view work correctly and show angular Component  but when get it from SQL is just shown a text

Html Code come from DB with SP   with NVarchar

TSCode :

```
  this.stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(this.postdata);
  this.helpService.GetComponentContent(this.uRL_Address, this.sp_Name, 
  this.stringifiedData).subscribe(val => {
  this.tableJSon = val;
  this.stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(this.tableJSon);
  this.Table_JS_Data = JSON.parse(this.stringifiedData);
```

Html

```
  {{this.Table_JS_Data[0].HtmlCode}}
```

and the result is

[image]

problem is i want to show it like a angular component not a text is that Possible ?
Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible. Component templates need to be compiled to actual html, and this won't happen at runtime browser-side if you insert it as html.

You can use solution proposed by alifnaiech in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73219565/4550158), but this will only work for the actual valid html that browser can interpret, and using angular components that are not embedded into app as [web components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) will not work.

If you expect to have fairly structured content of the "components" coming from back-end, you can re-work this to actually store json that represents this structure, and use static generic template to render the "component" using that json using some `*ngIf`, `*ngFor`, etc.

If that's not the case, you could use [ComponentFactory](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactory) (documentation includes a link to a tutorial on using dynamic components) to handle more complicated cases.

Comment: ComponentFactory Create Component ?  pass the html & ts code to this function and create a component ? thats Deprecated

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way :

```
<div [innerHTML]="Table_JS_Data[0].HtmlCode"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular renders everything inside `{{...}}` as string interpolation, so in order to achieve actual HTML rendering you need to bind it to the `innerHTML` HTML property.

So it can work like this:

```html
<div [innerHTML]="this.Table_JS_Data[0].HtmlCode"></div>
```